# Reliable way of listening to events on frontend

Tags: web3js, events, infura, web3-providers

I make a web application, that needs the events from my contract to initialize it's state. I was using infura websocket provider, but it seems to lag a lot and close the connections unexpectedly during the last week. `getPastEvents` method does not work well.

I would like for my application to be accessible from smartphones (at least for read only mode). So I cannot rely only on the node or wallet running on same computer.

Is there a way to get all the events from some contract in a reliable way? For example, how does etherdelta achieve this? They run a server, with it's own private node, that generates static data every block?

Answer (score 1):

You can use event watch on each transaction call then able to get the event from Tx receipts.

**Sample code**

```
const self = this;
this.props.deposit(this.state.amount).then((result) => {
    if (!result) {
        Message.error('XYZ')
    }

    var event = self.props.getEventXXX()
    event.watch(function (err, response) {
        if(response.event == 'XXX') {
            notification.success({
                message: 'ABC',
                description: 'XYZ!',
            });
            event.stopWatching()
        }
    });
```

You can refer to this document also: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events

Comment: That's a good idea! But I really need to load the past events. It would be to costly to store all the needed information in the contract.

Comment: You can get past events of any specific transaction from it's receipts/logs and it's not called listening to events as your title; just read data from blockchain.